# Low lighting leads to low fps when recording video

Tags: android, video-capture

I am writing an application which has a video recording feature. During normal day-light hours with lots of light I am able to get 30fps video to record.

However, when there is less light, the frame rate drops to around 7.5fps (with exactly the same code). My guess would be that android is doing something behind the scenes with the exposure time to ensure that the resulting video has the best image quality.

I, however, would prefer a higher fps to a better quality image. Assuming exposure is the issue, is there any way to control the exposure time to ensure a decent fps (15fps+). There are the functions `setExposureCompensation()` and `setAutoExposureLock()` but they seem to do nothing.

Has anyone had this issue before? Is it even exposure that is causing my issue?

Any hits/suggestions would be great.

Comment: Have you tried this on multiple devices? The issue could be the device you're using has an auto frame-rate. I found this in the docs for `MediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(...)`... **"NOTE: On some devices that have auto-frame rate, this sets the maximum frame rate, not a constant frame rate. Actual frame rate will vary according to lighting conditions."**

Comment: Interesting, I have set the frame rate in my code. How would one find out if I have an auto frame-rate device (Its a Google Nexus 7)...I've checked the parameters `flatten()` string but that didn't give anything as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple explanation here. The lower light means there is more noise in the video. With more noise the encoding engine has to put far more effort to get the compression it needs. Unless the encoder has a denoiser the encoding engine has far more noise to deal with than normal conditions.

If you want a more technical answer: More noise means that the motion-estimation engine of the encoder is thrown for a toss. This is the part that consumes maximum CPU cycles.  The more the noise, the worse the compression and hence even other parts of the encoder are basically crunching more. More bits are generated which means that the encoding and entropy engines are also crunching more and hence the worse performance.

Generally in high end cameras a lot of noise is removed by the imaging pipeline in the sensor. However don't expect that in a mobile phone sensor. [This is the ISO performance that you see in DSLRs ].

Comment: So exposure is not really the issue. If lighting is bad.. there is not much you can do. Over exposure will wash out what is visible.

Comment: Whilst I do understand what you are saying, there is no increase in CPU usage, its constant throughout use and fps drop.

Comment: @Ben, it is the same no, fps is dropping because the CPU usage is being kept constant as keeping the same fps would need higher CPU! So internally the CPU usage is being capped [to keep the system sane] and the fps varies.

Answer (score 6):

I am sorry but the accepted answer is totally wrong. In fact I have created an account just to correct this.

Noise information gets discarded depending on the bitrate anyway, I do not understand why someone would think that this would be an extra load on cpu at all.

In fact, video framerate on a mobile device has a lot to do with light exposure. In a low light situation, exposure is increased automatically, which also means the shutter will stay open longer to let more light in. Which will reduce the number of frames you can capture in a second, and add some motion blur on top. With a DSLR camera you could change your aperture for more light, without touching the shutter speeds, but on mobile devices your aperture is fixed.

You could mess with exposure compensation to get more fps, but I do not think super dark video is what you want.

---

**More information;**
https://anyline.com/news/low-end-android-devices-exposure-triangle/

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with Android 4.2 Galaxy S III. After experimenting with parameters found one call which started to work.

Look on Camera.Parameters, if you  print them out, you'll see:

```
preview-fps-range=15000,30000;
preview-fps-range-values=(8000,8000),(10000,10000),(15000,15000),(15000,30000),(30000,30000);
```

The `range` allows the fps to "slow down".

The call `setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);` enforces the fps to stay around 30.

Answer (score 1):

This is right, you should call `setPreviewFpsRange()` to get constant fps. The frame rate you see is dropping because of the CCD, when light is low the fps goes down so it can produce better pictures (in still mode).

Also to achieve higher frame rate you should use:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
parameters.setRecordingHint(true);
```

camera.setParameters(parameters);